# redis sync read replica on demand

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, redis, dump

i added a value into redis write replica

```
  LPUSH one valueone
```

and it is immediately available on read replica but i want to sync it manually

Q: i have some data in mongoDB and want to take that to redis (daily once) with minimum downtime on redis , 
so just planning to write all the data to write replica first and after it is done then sync write replica with read replica , 
so want to sync read replica on demand

i am using amazon aws elastic cache redis and read replica